# upgrade fail 20.04.1 LTS to 20.10

Tags: upgrade

Trying to upgrade from 20.04.1 LTS to 20.10 and get the below fail message. i within Software and updates changed notify me of a new Ubuntu version to 'for any new version' and when a popup appears asking me if i want to upgrade i click 'upgrade' the process advancers until the fail message appears.
any ideas how i can complete an upgrade.
I am and will probably be something of a novice regards Ubuntu, so dont assume I'll know what your talking about :)

W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., E:The repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates Release' does not have a Release file.

Comment: You will need to disable or remove that unsupported repo.  Go to your Settings -> Software and Updates and unselect that one in the Other Software tab.

Comment: thanks that worked